# Solution of a series equation containing $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

I have to find the coefficients $a_k$ for which the following equation is satisfied:
$$S(N)=\sum_{k=1}^Na_k\frac{\pi^{k+3}}{k+3}=-2\pi+\epsilon(N)$$ where $\epsilon(N)$ is an error depending on $N$. I suppose there are a lot of combinations of $\{a_1,a_2,...a_N \}$
solving the equation. Given $N$, how can I find one solution and the residual error $\epsilon(N)$?
Thanks

Comment: What constraints are there on $\epsilon(N)$? If none, any sequence $a_k$ will do.

Comment: $a_1 = -\frac{2}{\pi^3}$, $a_k=0$ for $k>1$. Then $\epsilon(N)=0$ for every $N\geq 1$

Comment: @DanielFischer: $|\epsilon(N)|\le \alpha$. I forgot to put it in the question. Thanks

Comment: Also, what constraints are there on the $a_k$. If you can pick arbitrary real numbers, see above, and variations thereof.

Comment: @DanielFischer: in my case, $|a_k|\lt 1$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: solution in my previous comment satisfies $|a_k|<1$. Are there any other constraints? Maybe $a_k\neq 0$?

Comment: @Adam: Yes, I should have every $a_k$ different from $0$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: Then you can take $a_1=-\frac{2}{\pi^3}$, and $a_k= (-1)^k\alpha\cdot\frac{k+3}{\pi^{k+3}}$ for $k>1$, so $\epsilon(N)=\alpha$ for even $N$, and $\epsilon(N)=0$ for odd $N$

Comment: @Adam: Ok. Your comment is an answer. If you put it in the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a_1=-\frac{2}{\pi^3}$, and $a_k= (-1)^k\alpha\cdot\frac{k+3}{\pi^{k+3}}$ for $k>1$. Then $S(2n-1)=-2\pi$ and $S(2n)=-2\pi+\alpha$, so $\epsilon(N) = 0$ for odd $N$ and $\epsilon(N)=\alpha$ for even $N$.